# How to define a Map in Protobuf 3.0?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I've defined a simple mini.proto file like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";
message EncodeRequest{
    required bytes payload = 1;
    maps<string,string> encoding_parameters = 2;
}
```

The protoc compiler (--version == libprotoc 3.0.0 installed from source from protobuf-python-3.0.0-alpha-3) reports:

```
protoc -I . --python_out=. --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=`which grpc_python_plugin` mini.proto
mini.proto:4:13: Expected field name.
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that it should be:

```
  map<string,string> encoding_parameters = 2;
```

(note the remove of s)

Comment: and how do we even use this map<string, string> in the code? I'm also trying to make it work but don't know how to pass this